# Sonar Scanner throws EOFException - can not read HTTP status line

Tags: svn, sonarqube, svnkit

When executing a local or jenkins-server based sonar scan, after a while (around 20 minutes of trying to analyze certain file) it throws the following error:

```
00:45:31.439 INFO: 21/57 files analyzed
00:45:31.688 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:45:31.688 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
00:45:31.689 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:45:31.690 INFO: Total time: 21:53.981s
00:45:31.973 INFO: Final Memory: 36M/127M
00:45:31.974 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:45:31.975 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file local_path_to_file.java
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:85)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:58)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmPublisher.publish(ScmPublisher.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.afterSensors(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:60)
        at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:90)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: can not read HTTP status line
svn: E175002: REPORT request failed on 'svn_path_to_file.java'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:888)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:354)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.doReport(DAVConnection.java:344)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getFileRevisionsImpl(DAVRepository.java:920)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getFileRevisions(SVNRepository.java:756)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:109)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteAnnotate.run(SvnRemoteAnnotate.java:30)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient.java:295)
        at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:83)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: can not read HTTP status line
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:460)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: can not read HTTP status line
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPParser.parseStatus(HTTPParser.java:45)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.readHeader(HTTPConnection.java:263)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:179)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
```

SVN is used as repository technology. I have no problems accesing the file neither connecting to the SonarQube server, tokens are validated as well as project name and code.

I have no clue why would it fail on that specific file **always**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The error is from SVNKit, not SVN. Try suggestion about spooling from https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-989.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after some try-and-error I got notice of SVN repository being somewhat unstable. Even witht this, after running the scan with the property sonar.scm.disabled=true allows to run the analisys properly except it can't reach some metadata from the repository. I'd venture a guess that the execution tries to collect some author data for the sonar report and fails. Enabling said property launches the scan but without some info, so I guess this is a workaround, not a full solution. SVN unstable status might affect it too.